# Cannot run android application, the app configuration is disabled

Tags: android

I can't run my application for some reason. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ2Wb.png) for illustrate that.

build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.android.demo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

If you need more information, write that. Thanks any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the intent-filter with MAIN action and LAUNCHER category from the MainActivity definition in the AndroidManifest.

Complete your AndroidManifest file by this snippet:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

With this intent filter you notify the Android OS, which is your the launcher Activity.